# Какую использовать базу данных для "windows form"?

Tags: c#

Приложение устанавливаться не будет. Нужна небольшая бд. Что подскажите использовать?

Comment: sqlite 9 символов

Comment: Embedded database: [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_database), [2](http://embedded-databases.com/) - выбирайте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если ты знаком с SQL синтаксисом и хочешь работать именно с ним - твой выбор SQLite.

В остальных случаях я могу посоветовать использовать Realm. На сколько я знаю он намного удобнее в использовании и лучше смотреть в его сторону.

Comment: А я хотел узнать. Он нормально будет работать как и SQL внутри приложения? Ничего докачивать не придется?

Comment: Nuget нужно будет скачать для работы с SQLite, если вопрос был именно в этом.

Comment: То есть если я отправлю на другой комп. То при запуске попросит SQLite установить?

Comment: @chilo5432 нет, если вы напишите программу и отправите её копию, то там при запуске SQLite устанавливать не надо будет

Comment: там будет в папке с программой лежать библиотека для работы с SQLite базами данных. А так же будет сама база данных (если ее создашь в папке с программой). Ничего дополнительно доустанавливать не нужно будет на каком бы компьютере ты бы не запускал. Но лично я советую реалм.

Answer (score 0):

Если база данных не большая попробуйте NoSql(MongoDB, Riak...)